# Update multiple rows in bigquery (Google Standard SQL dialect)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm running an sql query to update multiple rows at once. The below code works in mysql, but when I run it in bigquery PRIORITY is set to null. What is wrong with my syntax?

```
UPDATE griffinDataset
    SET PRIORITY = (case when SDC_LOCATIONID = 5920 then 1
                         when SDC_LOCATIONID = 5965 AND DFC_LOCATIONID = 5882 then 2
                         when SDC_LOCATIONID = 5362 AND DFC_LOCATIONID = 5882 then 3
                         when SDC_LOCATIONID = 5852 AND DFC_LOCATIONID = 5882 then 4 
                    end) WHERE 1=1;
```

Comment: Check your data, the code looks fine to me.

Comment: @griffin Looks like your syntax is ok. For better understanding  could you please add sample data and desired output to your question